# Как программно изменить цвет toolbar

Tags: java, android, actionbar, android-toolbar

Поставил toolbar, но не знаю как программно изменить его. Хотел попробовать через getSupportActionBar(), но там не было такого метода с помощью которого можно было изменить цвет

toolbar XML

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
```

toolbar установленный в методе OnCreate

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

Comment: вы хотите его динамически в программе изменять или просто изменить на нужный вам цвет?

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше всего создать отдельную тему, а при старте активити уже выбирать нужную с помощью `setTheme()`

Answer (score 5):

Программно можно так:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Так можно:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

или

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```